# What does it mean when a system is made dimensionless and what is the exact technique for that?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

For school research I'm working on a system of ODEs to describe a chemical oscillator (the Oregonator). This system is described with the following system:

$$ \frac {dX}{dt}=k_1AY-k_2XY+k_3AX-2k_4X^2 $$
$$ \frac{dY}{dt}=-k_1AY-k_2XY+\frac{1}{2}k_cfBZ  $$
$$ \frac{dZ}{dt}=2k_3AX-k_cBZ $$

The variables $k_- $ are all constants and so are $f$, A and B.

Most papers however go on to make it dimensionless. What does it exactly mean to make a system dimensionless (in chemistry) and what is the technique I should use to make a (or the above) system dimensionless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Begin by writing each variable as a constant of the same dimension, times a dimensionless variable. Then simplify your equations to cancel such constants. For example, let's write $X=X_0x$ with $X_0$ constant and $x$ dimensionless, and handle your other capitalized variables the same way. We also need to nondimensionalize time, e.g. with $t=t_0\tau$ where $t_0$ is a constant with the dimension of time. So$$\begin{align}\frac{dx}{d\tau}&=\frac{t_0}{X_0}\frac{dX}{dt}\\&=\frac{t_0}{X_0}\left(k_1A_0Y_0ay-k_2X_0Y_0xy+k_3A_0X_0ax-2k_4X_0^2x^2\right)\\&=K_1ay-K_2xy+K_3ax-2K_4x^2\end{align}$$where I've defined$$K_1:=\frac{t_0k_1A_0Y_0}{X_0},\,K_2:=t_0k_2Y_0,\,K_3:=t_0k_3A_0,\,K_4:=t_0k_4X_0.$$These constants are also dimensionless: for example, $K_1$ has the same dimension as the ratio of the dimensionless $dx/d\tau$ to the dimensionless $ay$. So if you go through all the equations this way, only dimensionless quantities will remain.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I now understand how to do this. Could you also explain shortly what the dimension actually is?

Comment: @ralphsmit It doesn't matter to our purposes, but: $A,\,X,\,Y$ have the dimensions of concentration, $t$ has the dimension of time, the $k_i$ (including $k_c$) each have the dimensions of (inverse concentration) over time, & $f$ is dimensionless because $k_cfBZ$ has the same dimension s $k_cBZ$.

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot!